# kubernetes ingress-nginx controller- connect() failed (111: connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: kubernetes, connection-refused, bad-gateway, ingress-nginx

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-skyway-host
  annotations:
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: "chat-srv-service"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  # tls:
  #   - hosts:

  #       - "focuspoint.shop"
  #     secretName: focuspoint-shop-tls
  rules:
    - host: "flyway.website"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/chat-srv/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: chat-srv-service
                port:
                  number: 4003
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /api/user-srv
            backend:
              service:
                name: user-srv-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /api/venture-srv
            backend:
              service:
                name: venture-srv-service
                port:
                  number: 3001
          - path: /api/admin-srv
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: admin-srv-service
                port:
                  number: 3002
          - path: "/"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv-service
                port:
                  number: 5173
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chat-srv-deployment
  labels:
    app: chat-srv
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chat-srv
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: chat-srv
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: chat-srv
          image: muhammedajmal/skyway-chat-srv:v14
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: chat-srv-service
spec:
  # type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: chat-srv
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 4003
      targetPort: 4003
```

Iam facing one of the error ..basically the problem is in microservices i have four services . i deployed to digital ocean k8s cluster . i gave here my ingress configration as well..every servervices are working fine except chat-srv-service ..it's not about chat problem ,The service did'nt get the API call's. when try to access the chat-srv-service showing bad gateway 502 error . when i check the k8s services object and deployment object everything is fine. when login the appropritate pod that also working fine ..there will be have no problem when describing the ingress that also perfect like the endpoints are correct . after ..iam try to access the chat base (chat service base api https://flyway.website/api/chat-srv/) api after checking the ingress logs there will be showing error like that image.(

> 2024/02/02 13:45:56 [error] 448#448: *1959729 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.158.22.16, server: flyway.website, request: "GET /api/chat-srv/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.244.0.36:4003/api/chat-srv/", host: "flyway.website"

> 2024/02/02 14:07:02 [crit] 448#448: *1970788 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 10.122.0.5, server: 0.0.0.0:443)
> [!Errror showing like this when login ingress:- (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egb3A.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egb3A.jpg)

container is running fine . But Api call not reaching to chat-srv

Any one resolved like This issue.. please share you experience and how you solve this.That could be very help for me

Comment: Statement like `when i check the k8s services object and deployment object everything is fine.` doesn't help please add service, deployment and also how did you tested from within a pod, I guess it can be something like your `chat-srv` expects https connection but ingress is forwarding it as http or something like this

Comment: Okay. now i have added the deployment and service yaml files

Comment: when i login the pod .. is working fine . there will be no issues run container inside the pod

Comment: When you start new pod by calling `kubectl run test -it --rm --image=alpine --restart=Never -- ash` then `apk add curl` then call `curl -v http://chat-srv-service:4003` is it working? maybe app inside pod is listening on `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: no!! it's not working , showing like this
/ # curl -v http://chat-srv-service:4003
```
* Host chat-srv-service:4003 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 10.245.153.153
*   Trying 10.245.153.153:4003...
* connect to 10.245.153.153 port 4003 from 10.244.0.3 port 40004 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to chat-srv-service port 4003 after 8 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
curl: (7) Failed to connect to chat-srv-service port 4003 after 8 ms: Couldn't connect to server
/ #
```

Comment: Login into your `chat-srv` POD and call `netstat -tln`

Comment: showing like this 
/app # netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
/app #

Comment: How did you decide that app is working from within a POD?

Comment: when checkin the log of the pod it is running 4003 . in chat-srv i'm printing there if server is running it will be show the server running 4003 and if db is connected it will show db connected success..
i will give you here the log of the pod 

> chat-srv@1.0.0 start
> ts-node-dev app.ts

[INFO] 14:42:52 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.2, typescript ver. 5.3.3)
Chat service listening on Port = 4003
mongodb connected succesful

Comment: When it looks like log is a lie, you can try one more thing from within `char-srv` POD call `curl -v 127.0.0.1:4003` is this failed, it's issue with your app not container/k8s

Comment: it's not failed ...it showed  like this i 
 Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 4003
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:4003
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
etc........

Comment: one thing is everything ..iam not doing in locally instead of i bought cluster from digital ocean everything is working inside digital ocean cluster ..when i try to do the same thing in using cluster ip ..like ```curl -v <cluster-ip>:4003 it's failed`` it showing like this
connect to 64.225.84.130 port 4003 from 10.244.1.24 port 57146 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to 64.225.84.130 port 4003 after 131009 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 64.225.84.130 port 4003 after 131009 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Comment: So if it works from localhost but not from any other the issue in 99% cases is what I already wrote: app is listening on `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`

Comment: so what things i should do if i need to solve this issue

Comment: one thing i have noticed now when doing same thing like previously did..chat-service it's not working when doing that showing error like this / # curl -v chat-srv-service:4003
Host chat-srv-service:4003 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 10.245.153.153
*   Trying 10.245.153.153:4003...
* connect to 10.245.153.153 port 4003 from 10.244.0.118 port 35384 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to chat-srv-service port 4003 after 6 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
curl: (7) Failed to connect to chat-srv-service port 4003 after 6 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Comment: As your docker image is public I looked into it, as the issue is a little bit different, first in `src/config/server.ts` you are not verifying that `port` is a number, in your case it's string, because in `Dockerfile` you have `ENV PORT = 4003` that is valid but not what you expect because `PORT` is equal to `= 4003` when you are using space you shouldn't use `=` or use `=` without spaces around, when in the container you type `env` you will see `PORT== 4003`, express when you give it a `string` will create `unix socket file`, so when I started your app I see file `= 4003` in `/app`

Comment: Thanks Man ..i have fixed that issue ..issue is not related the docker or kubernetes . it's related to My application . there had some outdated npm Modules. that why api call not reaching there.